# MySQL: precompute data for better performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

Is it ok to precompute data for better performance? For example, when player wins a game, I count number of won games for the particular player and write it to a dedicated table. Then, when I show overall ratings, I don't need to count number of won games for the players once again — I already have it precomputed.

Of course, it's possible, that precomputed data becomes unsyncronized with real values, but it's bearable.

Or is there another, more "professional" way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Careful about premature optimization...

Answer (score 4):

No, its perfectly fine and is mostly done for large datasets you'd else had to perform sum/count/group by statements that cost alot performance.

if "out of sync" is not a problem to realtime, use nightly-jobs to verify they are still in sync, or update them if they are not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's also a new question: how to run those background jobs and not to slower the server? Should I just CRON some php scripts to verify/fix the data or there are better ways of doing the thing?

Comment: Minor addition/correction: most DBs that require such information to be in-synch in real-time (or approximating real-time) may update such pre-computed values immediately or on schedule

Comment: @ starter, you can also deploy functions into your mysql database and use the event system to crunch through them ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html ) plus German arlington is correct - thats why I said if its not a huge problem. If it was, he needed to either add daily/current values to the precomputed ones until next full-sync is run or verify them "on insert"

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches are used -

1. Store aggregate values in separate summary tables
2. Store aggregate values against original table

There's no right or wrong answer. Probably in your case you want to use 1) so you have an aggregate table like:

PlayerID
AggregateName
AggregateValue

Then you can extend your aggregates easily without having to modify the table structure.